# Grunt usemin processing paths located in js files?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

Currently i have a few html files that look like this:

```
 <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/moduleX-scripts.js -->
  <script src="scripts/moduleX/moduleXConfig.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/moduleX/featureX/controller.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/moduleX/featureX/service.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/moduleX/featureY/controller.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/moduleX/featureY/service.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

 <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/moduleY-scripts.js -->
  <script src="scripts/moduleY/moduleYConfig.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/moduleY/featureW/controller.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/moduleY/featureW/service.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/moduleY/featureZ/controller.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/moduleY/featureZ/service.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

Since this is an angular application, i would like to use [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) for managing my modules, so my configuration would look something like this:

```
angular.module('MyMainModule', [
  {
    name: 'moduleX',
    files: [
      'scripts/moduleX/moduleXConfig.js',
      'scripts/moduleX/featureX/controller.js',
      'scripts/moduleX/featureX/service.js',
      'scripts/moduleX/featureY/controller.js',
      'scripts/moduleX/featureY/service.js',
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'moduleY',
    files: [
      'scripts/moduleY/moduleYConfig.js',
      'scripts/moduleY/featureW/controller.js',
      'scripts/moduleY/featureW/service.js',
      'scripts/moduleY/featureZ/controller.js',
      'scripts/moduleY/featureZ/service.js',
    ]
  }
  ])
```

Is there any grunt plugin that would process this .js file and replace the `files` array with minified and revisioned version?

Comment: Hey @gerasalus, I am stuck on this exact thing. Were you able to figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grunt-contrib-uglifyjs` to minify your files.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    moduleX: {
      files: {
        'scripts/moduleX.min.js': ['scripts/moduleX/*.js']
      }
    },
    moduleY: {
      files: {
        'scripts/moduleY.min.js': ['scripts/moduleY/*.js']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The only change you would need to make would be to include a file that declared your module in your module directory. For example, within the `scripts/moduleX` directory, you would have the following file:

```
// scripts/modeulX.js
angular.module('moduleX', []);
```